# Adding keys to defaultdict(dict)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a defaultdict that looks like this:

```
my_dict = defaultdict(dict)
```

which will print out:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {})
```

I also have two lists, which look like this:

```
list1 =  ["W", "IY", "W"]
list2 =  ["w", "ee", "w"]
```

I would like to create a default dict which looks like this:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'W': {'w': 2}, 'IY': {'ee': 1}}
```

which has list1 within a dictionary as keys, with the keys as the next list with a separate dictionary, counting the instances of list2 as values.

So far I have this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

list1 = ["W", "IY", "W"]
list2 = ["w", "ee", "w"]

for char in list1:
    d[char] += 1
```

I know that this is not correct, as the defaultdict(dict) cannot be treated this way. Is there a way a I could do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are the lists always the same length, and are all in list1 upper- and in list2 lowercase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED based on the comment on my original answer.

You'll need a mapping of all possible phonemes to all possible spellings (graphemes).

```
phonemes = {TH : [th], O : [o], OH : [oh, oo]}

for char in set(list1):
    if char not in d:
        d[char] = {char.lower() : {phone : list2.count(phone) for phone in phonemes[char]}}
```

Comment: If your lists are really big you could add a check to see if char is already in d.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution using `collections.Counter`.

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)

list1 = ["O", "TH", "O", "O"]
list2 = ["o", "th", "o", "o1"]

for key, value in zip(list1, list2):
    d[key].update([value])

>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {'TH': Counter({'th': 1}), 'O': Counter({'o': 2, 'o1': 1})})
>>>
```

While this doesn't strictly follow your requirements, `collections.Counter` inherits from `dict` so it has all of `dict`'s attributes

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a nested defaultdict and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) like so:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for k, v in zip(list1, list2):
    d[k][v] += 1
# d['TH']['th']: 1
# d['O']['o']: 2
```

or, if you want to keep your data structure:

```
d = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in zip(list1, list2):
    d[k][v] = d[k].get(v, 0) + 1  
    # use dict.get(key, default=None) and specify an appropriate default value (0)
```

Using [`dict.get(key, default=None)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) allows you to access key-values of a common `dict` much like those a defaultdict, however, updating is a little more clunky.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different take on a solution:

```
import collections

phonemes  = ["W", "IY", "O", "W", "O"]
graphemes = ["w", "ee", "o", "w", "oh"]

# count all the (phoneme, grapheme) pairs
counter = collections.Counter(zip(phonemes, graphemes))

# convert to desired data structure
d = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for (phoneme, grapheme), count in counter.items():
    d[phoneme][grapheme] = count

print(d)
```

prints:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'W': {'w': 2}, 'O': {'oh': 1, 'o': 1}, 'IY': {'ee': 1}})
```